# Error in configuration file

Tags: php, configuration

I have copied my project folder from my live server to my local host and edited the config file as per localhost, but still i am displayed with the "Internal Server Error:500"

> The server encountered an internal
>   error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server
>   administrator, admin@localhost and
>   inform them of the time the error
>   occurred, and anything you might have
>   done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may
>   be available in the server error log.

I cannot understand what should be the problem here, please help me to track the issue here....

Comment: You'll have to show some code. Otherwise we can only guess what's wrong. Maybe have a look into your error.log as well.

Comment: Yeah, the 500 error doesn't tell you anything. Almost anything could be wrong with the server.

Comment: Also 500 errors can be created by .htaccess files (perhaps you have modules that aren't available that are being implicitly required by entries) - as already pointed out, though, it could be anything..

Comment: I suggest you look in `error.log` / `access.log`. That should provide interesting info.

Comment: check your httpd.conf if running apache and php.ini for errors/recent changes. maybe try rolling back to the default config. DH: +1 for .htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found It, There was an issue with the apache setting, rewrite module was not activated... I rectified it..
Thank you all for your Guideline....